# How do I get MySQL data in to a combobox

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I like to know how to get all the data from mysql table to a combobox in a form and display. i have a table name datapack and in that table have id. category and description. i need to display all the fields in the category from a combobox. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="items">  
<php  
// assuming that you use mysql fetch array to get you data
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))    
{echo "<option value='".$row[id]."'>".$row[name]."</option>";}  
?>
</select>
```

This creates a simple drop down list in HTML. You can add additional functionality using Javascript. [jQuery is your friend](http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-jquery-select-box-manipulation-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

A combobox isn't natively available in HTML, but you could use a dropdown+text box, or make a combobox yourself using jQuery or something similar to that. After that it's pretty straightforward, you just loop through your table and display the items in the right tags, that's it.